# Android Programming Prefrences Activity using Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Im trying to create a preferences fragment. However i keep getting an error. Any help would extremely be appreciated! If you have any good links for preferences please comment them! Thank you so much!!

```
    package com.example.rifatrashid.mycalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 //Some random variables!!!
 public static double firstNumber;
 public static double secondNumber;
 public static Integer clickCount = 0;
 public static boolean mult, divide, sub, plus, clicked = false;
 public static double result;
 public static TextView status;
 public static TextView calcText;``
 public static String operation;
 private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;
 public static UserSettingActivity settings = new UserSettingActivity();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {


    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */



public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.IOSpink));
        //Attach listeners to all the buttons:
        //Number 0
         calcText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calcText);
        status = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusText);

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibe.vibrate(100);
                calcText.setText("");
                clickCount = 0;
            }
        });
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                calcText.append("0");
            }
        });

        //Number 1
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    calcText.append("1");
            }
        });

        //Number 2
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("2");
            }
        });

        //Number 3
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("3");
            }
        });

        //Number 4
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("4");
            }
        });

        //Number 5
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("5");
            }
        });

        //Number 6
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("6");
            }
        });

        //Number 7
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button7).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("7");
            }
        });

        //Number 8
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                   calcText.append("8");
            }
        });

        //Number 9
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                    calcText.append("9");
            }
        });

        //Multiply Button
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                package1("multiply", "×");
            }
        });

        //Button Divide
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                package1("divide", "÷");
            }
        });

        //Button Subtract
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSubtract).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                package1("minus", "-");
            }
        });

        //Button Add
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddition).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                package1("plus", "+");
            }
        });

        //Button Decimal
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimal).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                calcText.append(".");
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container,settings)
                        .commit();

            }
        });

        //Button Equals
        final TextView st = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calcText);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonEquals).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vib.vibrate(100);
                if(clickCount > 0){
                    try {
                        if (operation == "plus") {
                            secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(calcText.getText().toString());
                            Double res = Addition(firstNumber, secondNumber);
                            calcText.setText(res.toString());
                        }
                        if (operation == "minus") {
                            secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(calcText.getText().toString());
                            Double res = Subtraction(firstNumber,    secondNumber);
                            calcText.setText(res.toString());
                        }
                        if (operation == "multiply") {
                            secondNumber =     Double.parseDouble(calcText.getText().toString());
                            Double res = Multiply(firstNumber,     secondNumber);
                            calcText.setText(res.toString());
                        }
                        if (operation == "divide") {
                            secondNumber = Double.parseDouble(calcText.getText().toString());
                            Double res = Divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
                            calcText.setText(res.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                       clickCount = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
public static class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
}

public static double Divide(double firstnumber, double secondnumber){
    result = firstnumber/secondnumber;
    return result;
}

public static double Multiply(double firstnumber, double secondnumber){
    result = firstnumber * secondnumber;
    return result;
}

public static double Addition (double firstnumber, double secondNumber){
    result = firstnumber + secondNumber;
    return  result;
}

public static double Subtraction (double firstnumber, double secondNumber){
    result = firstnumber - secondNumber;
    return  result;
}

public static void package1(String Operation, String Status){
    firstNumber = Double.parseDouble(calcText.getText().toString());
    calcText.setText("");
    status.setText(Status);
    operation = Operation;
    clickCount++;
    }
}



02-18 14:23:46.363    8384-8384/com.example.rifatrashid.mycalc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rifatrashid.mycalc, PID: 8384
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
        at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:299)
        at com.example.rifatrashid.mycalc.MainActivity$UserSettingActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:298)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2031)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at
```

Comment: your problem concern maybe your fragment.
"Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file" ,    your fragment doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post you settings.xml file please ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is an error in your layout (XML-File). Check for any errors and post the layout's code here if you need further help.